# How to handle Strings in a Panda Dataframe?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with some text features, ie a feature called "job" with some occurrence such as 'policeman', 'Lawyer', 'doctor' etc.
As in the following Python code :

```
    import pandas as pd
    dict = {'age' : [19, 35, 47], 'job' : ['policeman', 'lawyer', 'doctor']}
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

I'd like to know a way to convert the strings in jobs into int such as 0, 1, 2 so 'policeman' is the category 0, 'lawyer' the category number 1 etc..

More Broadly, my question is to find a way to compute efficiently predictions on this dataset with standard Librairies (Sklearn for instance). Since they don'y support strings as a feature I thought I could manually convert them to int. Is it really a good idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use them as features in your prediction the Allen's answer is correct, and you use a onehotencoding.

But if you want to do what you asked, this code could be helpful

```
map_dict = {'policeman':0, 'lawyer':1, 'doctor':2}
df.job = df.job.map(map_dict)
```

Comment: It is the best solution provided. Since Sklearn's label encoder sticks to alphabetical order, and it's impossible to overwrite that.

Comment: Ok great thank you. Could you tick the answer as correct then ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) to do this:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df['job_code'] = le.fit_transform(df.job)
```

This will transform your job variable to a numerical representation"

```
    age job         job_code
0   19  policeman   2
1   35  lawyer      1
2   47  doctor      0
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your actual question ("how do I create a column of numbers representing categories, based on a column of repeated strings"):

You can create a new numerical column to your categories by creating a list of the unique strings, and then asking each string in the column what's its index in that list:

```
import pandas as pd 
d = {'age' : [19, 35, 47, 31, 29],
     'job' : ['policeman', 'lawyer', 'doctor', 'lawyer', 'doctor']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

jobs = list(df.job.unique())
df['job_cat'] = df.job.apply(lambda x: jobs.index(x))

# resulting dataframe:
#    age        job  job_cat
# 0   19  policeman        0
# 1   35     lawyer        1
# 2   47     doctor        2
# 3   31     lawyer        1
# 4   29     doctor        2
```

Although if your goal is to one-hot encode your categories for machine learning, you should really be using [scikit-learn's OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).